# AWS Install SSL Certificate from Amazon Certificate Manager to EC2 Ubuntu

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2

I am using AWS and I'm trying to get an SSL Certificate up and running, I have done the following:

- Created an instance via EC2 and installed Ubuntu on that instance, all my code is on there and is working with http
- Added an A record for my domain via Route 53. All is working there, I am able to goto my domain and see the website that is on Ubuntu.
- Created a public SSL Certificate via Amazon Certificate Manager. I added the CNAME to where my domain was hosted, but the status never changed to Success so I added the CNAME via Route 53 where my A record is and I now have a status of Success.

I really don't know what to do next, I tried following the steps here:
https://hackernoon.com/getting-a-free-ssl-certificate-on-aws-a-how-to-guide-6ef29e576d22

But that did not work, can anyone point me in the right direction on what I am suppose to do next? When I try to goto my website with https I get error saying the site cant be reached.

[image]

Comment: Have you added a load balancer or CloudFront distribution in front of your domain?

Comment: Whatever is in that link is what I did

Answer (score 0):

You need to add load balancer listener and target group.Need to create two PATH 80 -> 443 redirection and 443 -> actual target group. 443 listener can have the certificate. (If its validated in ACM). See the attached image.Add Route53 -> Load Balancer. When you load the website it will pic the certificate from load balancer.
[image]

Thanks

Ashish

Comment: Also you can try to access direct loadbalancer URL it will show you website with certificate.

Comment: I did all that and it did not work, I went to direct loadbalancer URL and I got a 503 error on http and on https I get Not Secure Connection error.

Comment: have you defined redirect path correct in http? 503 is service unavailable.And in 443  It seems may be when you did your SSL was not in success state.

Comment: My SSL Certificate status says success.

Comment: Can you share your listener rules?

Comment: I added my listeners to my questions, is that what you were looking for?

Comment: You see my screenshot 80 -> 443 if you want to access only https. redirecting to 443.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217331/discussion-between-user979331-and-ashish-bhatia).